# Trying to access instantiated object in 2d array Unity c#. Cant access or change elements?

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array, unity-game-engine

First time question here.
I'm trying to build a game board like one you would see playing chess. I've made two scripts, one that spawns the board and stores each instantiated tile in a 2d array. And another script that sets the row and column location and `onMouseOver` prints that location to the console. However this is always print `Row = 0` and `Col = 0`.

I've come to the conclusion that the 2d array is just setting a clone in memory and therefor the stored values I set via calling the function `setRC();` are not being being found as the instantiated objects the the Unity scene don't share the memory location.

Anyone have an idea as to how I can fix this?

```
public class Map : MonoBehaviour {

public static int Row = 7;
public static int Col = 7;


private GameObject[,]boardPiece = new GameObject[Row,Col];

public GameObject prefab;
public GameObject prefab2;

void Start () {
    for (int i = 0; i < Row; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < Col; j++) 
        {
            if(i%2 ==1 && j%2 ==1 || i%2 ==0 && j%2 ==0)
            {
                boardPiece[i,j] = (GameObject)Instantiate(prefab, new Vector3(i*4.0f,0,j*4.0f),Quaternion.identity);
            }else{
                boardPiece[i,j] = (GameObject)Instantiate(prefab2, new Vector3(i*4.0f,0,j*4.0f),Quaternion.identity);
            }
            boardPiece[i,j].GetComponent<BoardPiece>().setRC(i,j);
        }

    }

}

    }

public class BoardPiece : MonoBehaviour {

private int rowPlace;
private int colPlace;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    rowPlace = 0;
    colPlace = 0;

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

}

void OnMouseOver(){
    string message = "Row: " + rowPlace + " Col: " + colPlace;
    print (message);
}

 public void setRC(int R, int C)
{
    rowPlace = R;
    colPlace = C;
    print ("set " + rowPlace + "," + colPlace);
}

}
```

Comment: @sarbbottam Thank you for your edits to my question. Very much appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without [a complete code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (difficult or even impractical to provide for Unity3d projects I know, but still...) it is difficult to know for sure what the problem is. However…

While the `Start()` method is often used in a fashion similar to a constructor, it's important to understand that it's not in fact one. I don't think it's called yet by the time your code is calling the `setRC()` method on your new object.

This means that the flow of execution is that you first set the row and column values as desired, and then later the `BoardPiece.Start()` method is called by the Unity3d framework, setting the row and column values back to `0`.

Since the `rowPlace` and `colPlace` fields are already set to `0` by default when the object is created, I think the best fix is to just remove those two lines from the `Start()` method altogether. They aren't needed, and I believe they are responsible for the problem you are having.